# put image from sd card to imageview in android

Tags: android

I have to place image from sd card to `imageview` in android

I tried using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. It is showing deprecated method. It is not working.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        try {
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/mm.png");

            imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
        }

//        File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/DCIM/mm.png");
//
//        if(imgFile.exists()) {
//
//            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
//
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
//        }


    }

}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    tools:context = ".MainActivity"
    android:orientation = "vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried many ways. But it is not working. Kindly suggest me to do this.

Comment: just load the path into imageview using glide or picasso library.

`Glide.with(context).loadUrl(path).into(imageView);`

Answer (score 0):

Manifest Add this permission:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

declare this on your Activity:

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private Context mContext=MainActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;
static ImageView muyimage;
```

in Oncreate();

```
muyimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimge);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
        } else {
            try {
 //here i have mentioned my image path ,you have to set your image path
                Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pictures/Screenshots/mine.png");

                muyimage.setImageBitmap(picture);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
            }
        }
    } else {
        try {
 //here i have mentioned my image path ,you have to set your image path
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pictures/Screenshots/mine.png");

            muyimage.setImageBitmap(picture);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

And this

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //do here
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write in your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
 //here i have mentioned my image path ,you have to set your image path
                    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Pictures/Screenshots/mine.png");

                    muyimage.setImageBitmap(picture);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Both of the methods are not working. Image is not displaying

Comment: kindly post the full code that you tried to get sd card image @sridhar

Comment: i have updated my Answer,100 percentage this answer will work ,i have checked. @sridhar

Comment: what kind of error you got, and  check image extension .png or .jpg, because this code perfectly working for me, after checking this code only I ave posted here

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the primary storage directory of the phone (`/storage/emulated/0/`) not `SD card`. The path of SD card storage varies from phone to phone and it depends on manufactures how to implement it. Sometimes SD card mounts to a folder with different names in `/storage` directory and sometimes in `/mnt` directory. Starting from Android `KitKat` (API 19) you have access to `getExternalFilesDirs` method to get storages directory but there isn't any official solution to work in all phones and android versions. Most of the time `SD card` mounts to `/storage` directory so I wrote a solution that works in the android emulator and most of the Android phones but it doesn't `guarantee` all possibilities. You could change your code like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        File storageDir = new File("/storage/");
        if(storageDir.exists()){
            String[] dirList = storageDir.list();
            for (String dir: dirList){
                if(!(dir.equals("emulated") || dir.equals("self"))){
                    File file = new File( "/storage/" + dir + "/DCIM/" + "mm.png");
                    if(file.exists()) {
                        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);

                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```